# Google Cloud and Active Directory hybrid scenario

Tags: google-cloud-platform, active-directory

I'm stuck in understanding the Google Hybrid scenario with Active Directory forest synchronization between on-premise and Google Cloud Platform, as per the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/patterns-for-using-active-directory-in-a-hybrid-environment#synchronized_forests).

The best practices states:

> Don't synchronize user account passwords between the two Active Directory forests. Doing so undermines the isolation between the environments.

Therefore, if only the user account is synchronized with no password, then how come a user can successfully login into the GCP Active Directory?

Comment: Separate forests are like separate computers. You login to the correct system. I think you are thinking of synchronizing the same forest between on-prem and the cloud.

Comment: @JohnHanley my point is how can it be that accounts are synchronized without password ? (note that here the hypothesis is that there is no pass-through authentication). In GCP I would find usernames without pwd, so how can those username login?

Comment: Normally you do not synchronize passwords between accounts in different forests. They are separate identities. That is the point that Google mentioned in the article. That section talks about security, not convenience. Each identity has their own password. If an account has no password, then you cannot login to that account.